# code lines not getting executed or debugger not getting executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have this redux saga code and I am trying to debug it by introducing debugger at places in the code.
Here is the saga code that I am trying to debug.

```
function* cricketMatchCardClickHandler({ matchId, matchBaseUrl }) {
  try {
    const authToken = yield select(state => state.auth.authToken);
    console.log("authToken", authToken);
    if (!authToken) {
      yield* fetchCricketDraftPlayers({ matchId });
      yield put({ type: RESET_CRICKET_FANTASY_PLAYER_SELECTION });
      history.push(matchBaseUrl + "/pick-players");
    } else {
      debugger; // this debugger gets executed
      const sportsFanDraftGameDetails = yield call(
        getSportsFanDraftGameDetails,
        authToken,
        matchId
      );

      console.log("sportsFanDraftGameDetails", sportsFanDraftGameDetails);
      debugger; // this debugger didn't get executed
      yield put({
        type: FETCH_SPORTS_FAN_DRAFT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
        response: sportsFanDraftGameDetails
      });
      debugger;
      if (sportsFanDraftGameDetails) {
        history.push(matchBaseUrl + "/dashboard/timeline");
      } else {
        yield* fetchCricketDraftPlayers({ matchId });
        yield put({ type: RESET_CRICKET_FANTASY_PLAYER_SELECTION });
        history.push(matchBaseUrl + "/pick-players");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    debugger;
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

I see that even console log doesn't executed. What does this exactly mean and how is this related to the redux saga? How can we go about rectifying it?

Comment: If you console.log(state); outside of the try {} block is there something in it? What about after the authToken assignment, try authToken.next(); what happens in the console.log() then?

Comment: `call` is blocking effect, so it mean `getSportsFanDraftGameDetails` yet not finished, You can debug it.

Comment: @cyrilluce hey could you please explain as of how to debug it?

Comment: @godfather_satyajeet like what you are doing, add debugger, or just add breakpoint on chrome DevTools

Comment: I just introduced debugger.I want to console logs things and as things are .